# Saving File to Dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any way to save a file to a dictionary under python?
(Indeed I am not asking how to export dictionaries to files here.)

Maybe a file could be pickled or transformed into me python object
and then saved.

Is this generally advisable?
Or should I only save the file's path to the dictionary?

How would I retrieve the file later on?

The background of my question relates to my usage of dictionaries as 
databases. I use the handy little module sqlitshelf as a form of permanent dictionary: https://github.com/shish/sqliteshelf

Each dataset includes a unique config file (~500 kB) which is retrieved from an application. Upon opening of the respective data set the config file are copied into and back from the  working directory of the application. I might use a folder instead where I save the config files to. Yet, it strikes me as more elegant to save them together with the other data.

Comment: You can put the file's text in a dictionary:  `dct = {'file_text': somefile.read()}`.  If you really need to treat this file's text as a file later, you can wrap it in an `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO` instance later.  `file_like = io.StringIO(dct['file_text'])`

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion, mgilson! It sounds like a reasonable idea to me. Still I wait for further suggestions to eventually get different perspectives.

Comment: How do you plan to use this file in a dictionary? @mgilson shows you how to read the text, but what's the point? How would it be useful? A sqlite database file should be kept on disk. A config file should be parsed into usable python object (maybe ConfigParser, xml, yaml or whatever ,depending on the config file format). I don't see a use for just having the text in memory.

Comment: @mgilson , what about: `dct = {'file_text': somefile.read}`, and only when you really have to you do a `dct['file_text']()` to get the content?

Comment: @ReutSharabani -- It looks like OP is serializing the dct and storing it in some sort of DB for future use.  I'm pretty sure that file handles aren't easily serialized, so that probably wouldn't work.

Comment: Just throwing it out there for someone with a fitting use case :)

Comment: Thanks four suggestions. I am storing cookie files for webrowser testing. I use the squliteshelf module for permanent data storage in a dictionary object. It suits my purposes well, as it is partiuclarly easy to use. I will test out mgilson's and Reut Sharabani's answers in the coming days.